# Converting "yield from" statement to Python 2.7 code

Tags: python, generator, python-2.x, yield, yield-from

I had a code below in Python 3.2 and I wanted to run it in Python 2.7. I did convert it (have put the code of `missing_elements` in both versions) but I am not sure if that is the most efficient way to do it. Basically what happens if there are two `yield from` calls like below in upper half and lower half in `missing_element` function? Are the entries from the two halves (upper and lower) appended to each other in one list so that the parent recursion function with the `yield from` call and use both the halves together?

```
def missing_elements(L, start, end):  # Python 3.2
    if end - start <= 1: 
        if L[end] - L[start] > 1:
            yield from range(L[start] + 1, L[end])
        return

index = start + (end - start) // 2

# is the lower half consecutive?
consecutive_low =  L[index] == L[start] + (index - start)
if not consecutive_low:
    yield from missing_elements(L, start, index)

# is the upper part consecutive?
consecutive_high =  L[index] == L[end] - (end - index)
if not consecutive_high:
    yield from missing_elements(L, index, end)

def main():
    L = [10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20]
    print(list(missing_elements(L, 0, len(L)-1)))
    L = range(10, 21)
    print(list(missing_elements(L, 0, len(L)-1)))

def missing_elements(L, start, end):  # Python 2.7
    return_list = []                
    if end - start <= 1: 
        if L[end] - L[start] > 1:
            return range(L[start] + 1, L[end])

    index = start + (end - start) // 2

    # is the lower half consecutive?
    consecutive_low =  L[index] == L[start] + (index - start)
    if not consecutive_low:
        return_list.append(missing_elements(L, start, index))

    # is the upper part consecutive?
    consecutive_high =  L[index] == L[end] - (end - index)
    if not consecutive_high:
        return_list.append(missing_elements(L, index, end))
    return return_list
```

Comment: Most of the implementations below are lacking support in some regard (for sending values to generators, handling nested yield-froms, etc.). I published a package in PyPI that attempts to be comprehensive in the behavior: http://amir.rachum.com/yieldfrom/

Answer (score 96, accepted):

If you don't use the results of your yields,* you can *always* turn this:

```
yield from foo
```

… into this:

```
for bar in foo:
    yield bar
```

There might be a performance cost,** but there is never a semantic difference.

---

> Are the entries from the two halves (upper and lower) appended to each other in one list so that the parent recursion function with the yield from call and use both the halves together?

No! The whole point of iterators and generators is that you don't build actual lists and append them together.

But the *effect* is similar: you just yield from one, then yield from another.

If you think of the upper half and the lower half as "lazy lists", then yes, you can think of this as a "lazy append" that creates a larger "lazy list". And if you call `list` on the result of the parent function, you of course *will* get an actual `list` that's equivalent to appending together the two lists you would have gotten if you'd done `yield list(…)` instead of `yield from …`.

But I think it's easier to think of it the other way around: What it does is exactly the same the `for` loops do.

If you saved the two iterators into variables, and looped over `itertools.chain(upper, lower)`, that would be the same as looping over the first and then looping over the second, right? No difference here. In fact, you could implement `chain` as just:

```
for arg in *args:
    yield from arg
```

---

* Not the values the generator yields to its caller, the value of the yield expressions themselves, within the generator (which come from the caller using the `send` method), as described in [PEP 342](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/). You're not using these in your examples. And I'm willing to bet you're not in your real code. But coroutine-style code often uses the value of a `yield from` expression—see [PEP 3156](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3156/) for examples. Such code usually depends on other features of Python 3.3 generators—in particular, the new `StopIteration.value` from the same [PEP 380](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) that introduced `yield from`—so it will have to be rewritten. But if not, you can use the PEP also shows you the complete horrid messy equivalent, and you can of course pare down the parts you don't care about. And if you don't use the value of the expression, it pares down to the two lines above.

** Not a huge one, and there's nothing you can do about it short of using Python 3.3 or completely restructuring your code. It's exactly the same case as translating list comprehensions to Python 1.5 loops, or any other case when there's a new optimization in version X.Y and you need to use an older version.

Comment: A question how do the recursive calls work? Does the "yield from" parent function  combine two "yield from" statements in the child. if not consecutive_low:
    yield from missing_elements(L, start, index)

# is the upper part consecutive?
consecutive_high =  L[index] == L[end] - (end - index)
if not consecutive_high:
    yield from missing_elements(L, index, end)

Comment: @vkaul11: It works exactly like the loop does, except faster (and supporting various more complex cases the loop can't). If you want the gory details, read the PEP.

Comment: @abarnet Is the code not using the result from yield from in the subsequent recursion calls? I was trying to use somebody's code at work and running in Python 2.7, so wanted to understand why you say that. Does a "yield from recursive_function()" just loop over each nested yield in the recursive_function

Comment: @vkaul11: Not the values yielded from the generator to the caller, the values of the actual `yield` expressions, within the generator. This is hard to explain; see [PEP 342](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/) if you want to understand it, but briefly: if you never call `send` on a generator, or never do `foo = (yield bar)` inside the generator, and can't imagine why you'd ever want to do either… don't worry about it until you have time to read PEP 342 (and 380 and 3156 and Greg Ewing's nifty blog posts linked from 3156).

Comment: If anyone can suggest how to make that part clearer in the answer itself, please do!

Comment: @abarnet As I understand now  "yield from recursive_function()" just loops over each yield in the child recursive_function call. Right? I will look over your links. Thanks

Comment: When foo is empty, it's not the same I guess.

Comment: @trss: Nope, still the same. Both forms will do nothing. Compare [this](http://goo.gl/mtiLMc) and [this](http://goo.gl/sLZkVy); they both yield nothing, so they print out `done` then raise `StopIteration`. (They also both mark the function as a generator function despite not yielding anything, meaning you can `yield from ()` instead of `if False: yield None` to force a generator.)

Comment: Right. I'd gotten confused by the problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243766/python-empty-generator-function which is similar. I've now got a better understanding. Thank you.

Comment: In case you're on python 3.5+, trying to deal that way with native coroutines will result in `TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not iterable`

Comment: This seems very false, and I'm strongly tempted to downvote this. `yield from foo` will propagate any `.send` and `.throw` calls *you* received into `foo`, whereas `for bar in foo: yield foo` will not. Even if "you don't use the results of your yields", you can't know from just looking at `yield from foo` if *foo* is using the results of your yields. You might be transitively invisibly using them, but locally that looks like not using them, and you might not even think of exceptions raising from a `yield` as a "result" of your yields, so it seems horribly misleading to boil it down to that.

Answer (score 7):

Replace them with for-loops:

```
yield from range(L[start] + 1, L[end])

==>

for i in range(L[start] + 1, L[end]):
    yield i
```

The same about elements:

```
yield from missing_elements(L, index, end)

==>

for el in missing_elements(L, index, end):
    yield el
```

Answer (score 7):

I just came across this issue and my usage was a bit more difficult since I needed the *return value* of `yield from`:

```
result = yield from other_gen()
```

This cannot be represented as a simple `for` loop but can be reproduced with this:

```
_iter = iter(other_gen())
try:
    while True: #broken by StopIteration
        yield next(_iter)
except StopIteration as e:
    if e.args:
        result = e.args[0]
    else:
        result = None
```

Hopefully this will help people who come across the same problem. :)

Answer (score 7):

What about using the definition from [pep-380](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380) in order to construct a Python 2 syntax version:

The statement:

```
RESULT = yield from EXPR
```

is semantically equivalent to:

```
_i = iter(EXPR)
try:
    _y = next(_i)
except StopIteration as _e:
    _r = _e.value
else:
    while 1:
        try:
            _s = yield _y
        except GeneratorExit as _e:
            try:
                _m = _i.close
            except AttributeError:
                pass
            else:
                _m()
            raise _e
        except BaseException as _e:
            _x = sys.exc_info()
            try:
                _m = _i.throw
            except AttributeError:
                raise _e
            else:
                try:
                    _y = _m(*_x)
                except StopIteration as _e:
                    _r = _e.value
                    break
        else:
            try:
                if _s is None:
                    _y = next(_i)
                else:
                    _y = _i.send(_s)
            except StopIteration as _e:
                _r = _e.value
                break
RESULT = _r
```

In a generator, the statement:

```
return value
```

is semantically equivalent to

```
raise StopIteration(value)
```

except that, as currently, the exception cannot be caught by `except` clauses within the returning generator.

The StopIteration exception behaves as though defined thusly:

```
class StopIteration(Exception):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        if len(args) > 0:
            self.value = args[0]
        else:
            self.value = None
        Exception.__init__(self, *args)
```

Comment: +1 for actually basing an answer on the extensive definition in the PEP itself, which every other answer seemingly didn't even look at.

Answer (score 3):

I think I found a way to emulate Python 3.x `yield from` construct in Python 2.x. It's not efficient and it is a little hacky, but here it is:

```
import types

def inline_generators(fn):
    def inline(value):
        if isinstance(value, InlineGenerator):
            for x in value.wrapped:
                for y in inline(x):
                    yield y
        else:
            yield value
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        if isinstance(result, types.GeneratorType):
            result = inline(_from(result))
        return result
    return wrapped

class InlineGenerator(object):
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self.wrapped = wrapped

def _from(value):
    assert isinstance(value, types.GeneratorType)
    return InlineGenerator(value)
```

**Usage:**

```
@inline_generators
def outer(x):
    def inner_inner(x):
        for x in range(1, x + 1):
            yield x
    def inner(x):
        for x in range(1, x + 1):
            yield _from(inner_inner(x))
    for x in range(1, x + 1):
        yield _from(inner(x))

for x in outer(3):
    print x,
```

Produces output:

```
1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 3
```

Maybe someone finds this helpful.

**Known issues:** Lacks support for send() and various corner cases described in PEP 380. These could be added and I will edit my entry once I get it working.

Comment: What is the advantage of this solution, over abernert's earlier, simple solution, where convert to a for loop?

Comment: This needs to be an ActiveState recipe.

Comment: Nice implementation. Just remanding that the Trollius project (asyncio for Python < 3.3) does the same, with a `From` method. Its implementation is certainly production ready.

Comment: Thank you so much, it should be the accepted answer. I know I can do this use abarnert's way. But I want to find more effective way to do this, this is why I come to this page.

Answer (score 0):

I've found using resource contexts (using the [python-resources](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-resources) module) to be an elegant mechanism for implementing subgenerators in Python 2.7.  Conveniently I'd already been using the resource contexts anyway.

If in Python 3.3 you would have:

```
@resources.register_func
def get_a_thing(type_of_thing):
    if type_of_thing is "A":
        yield from complicated_logic_for_handling_a()
    else:
        yield from complicated_logic_for_handling_b()

def complicated_logic_for_handling_a():
    a = expensive_setup_for_a()
    yield a
    expensive_tear_down_for_a()

def complicated_logic_for_handling_b():
    b = expensive_setup_for_b()
    yield b
    expensive_tear_down_for_b()
```

In Python 2.7 you would have:

```
@resources.register_func
def get_a_thing(type_of_thing):
    if type_of_thing is "A":
        with resources.complicated_logic_for_handling_a_ctx() as a:
            yield a
    else:
        with resources.complicated_logic_for_handling_b_ctx() as b:
            yield b

@resources.register_func
def complicated_logic_for_handling_a():
    a = expensive_setup_for_a()
    yield a
    expensive_tear_down_for_a()

@resources.register_func
def complicated_logic_for_handling_b():
    b = expensive_setup_for_b()
    yield b
    expensive_tear_down_for_b()
```

Note how the complicated-logic operations only require the registration as a resource.

Comment: if the only thing your generator does is `yield from` another generator (exactly once always) then you could just return that generator instead. `get_a_thing` could replace both `yield from` with a `return` and it'd work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: by using my [`yield-from-as-an-iterator` library](https://pypi.org/project/yield-from-as-an-iterator), you can turn any `yield from foo` into

```py
for value, handle_send, handle_throw in yield_from(foo):
    try:
        handle_send((yield value))
    except:
        if not handle_throw(*sys.exc_info()):
            raise
```

To make sure this answer stands alone even if the PyPI package is ever lost, here is an entire copy of that library's `yieldfrom.py` from the 1.0.0 release:

```py
# SPDX-License-Identifier: 0BSD
# Copyright 2022 Alexander Kozhevnikov <mentalisttraceur@gmail.com>

"""A robust implementation of ``yield from`` behavior.
Allows transpilers, backpilers, and code that needs
to be portable to minimal or old Pythons to replace

    yield from ...

with

    for value, handle_send, handle_throw in yield_from(...):
        try:
            handle_send(yield value)
        except:
            if not handle_throw(*sys.exc_info()):
                raise
"""


__version__ = '1.0.0'
__all__ = ('yield_from',)


class yield_from(object):
    """Implementation of the logic that ``yield from`` adds around ``yield``."""

    __slots__ = ('_iterator', '_next', '_default_next')

    def __init__(self, iterable):
        """Initializes the yield_from instance.

        Arguments:
            iterable: The iterable to yield from and forward to.
        """
        # Mutates:
        #     self._next: Prepares to use built-in function next in __next__
        #         for the first iteration on the iterator.
        #     self._default_next: Saves initial self._next tuple for reuse.
        self._iterator = iter(iterable)
        self._next = self._default_next = next, (self._iterator,)

    def __repr__(self):
        """Represent the yield_from instance as a string."""
        return type(self).__name__ + '(' + repr(self._iterator) + ')'

    def __iter__(self):
        """Return the yield_from instance, which is itself an iterator."""
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        """Execute the next iteration of ``yield from`` on the iterator.

        Returns:
            Any: The next value from the iterator.

        Raises:
            StopIteration: If the iterator is exhausted.
            Any: If the iterator raises an error.
        """
        # Mutates:
        #     self._next: Resets to default, in case handle_send or
        #         or handle_throw changed it for this iteration.
        next_, arguments = self._next
        self._next = self._default_next
        value = next_(*arguments)
        return value, self.handle_send, self.handle_throw

    next = __next__  # Python 2 used `next` instead of ``__next__``

    def handle_send(self, value):
        """Handle a send method call for a yield.

        Arguments:
            value: The value sent through the yield.

        Raises:
            AttributeError: If the iterator has no send method.
        """
        # Mutates:
        #     self._next: If value is not None, prepares to use the
        #         iterator's send attribute instead of the built-in
        #         function next in the next iteration of __next__.
        if value is not None:
            self._next = self._iterator.send, (value,)

    def handle_throw(self, type, exception, traceback):
        """Handle a throw method call for a yield.

        Arguments:
            type: The type of the exception thrown through the yield.
                If this is GeneratorExit, the iterator will be closed
                by callings its close attribute if it has one.
            exception: The exception thrown through the yield.
            traceback: The traceback of the exception thrown through the yield.

        Returns:
            bool: Whether the exception will be forwarded to the iterator.
                If this is false, you should bubble up the exception.
                If this is true, the exception will be thrown into the
                iterator at the start of the next iteration, and will
                either be handled or bubble up at that time.

        Raises:
            TypeError: If type is not a class.
            GeneratorExit: Re-raised after successfully closing the iterator.
            Any: If raised by the close function on the iterator.
        """
        # Mutates:
        #     self._next: If type was not GeneratorExit and the iterator
        #         has a throw attribute, prepares to use that attribute
        #         instead of the built-in function next in the next
        #         iteration of __next__.
        iterator = self._iterator

        if issubclass(type, GeneratorExit):
            try:
                close = iterator.close
            except AttributeError:
                return False
            close()
            return False

        try:
            throw = iterator.throw
        except AttributeError:
            return False

        self._next = throw, (type, exception, traceback)
        return True
```

What I really like about this way is that:

1. The implementation is much easier to fully think through and *verify for correctness* than the alternatives*.
2. The usage is still simple, and doesn't require decorators or any other code changes anywhere other than just replacing the `yield from ...` line.
3. It still has robust forwarding of `.send` and `.throw` and handling of errors, `StopIteration`, and `GeneratorExit`.
4. This `yield_from` implementation will work on any Python 3 and on Python 2 all the way back to Python 2.5**.

<sub>* The formal specification ends up entangling all the logic into one big loop, even with some duplication thrown in. All the fully-featured backport implementations I've seen further add complication on top of that. But we can do better by embracing manually implementing the iterator protocol:</sub>

- <sub>We get `StopIteration` handling for free from Python itself around our `__next__` method.</sub>
- <sub>The logic can be split into separate pieces which are entirely decoupled except for the state-saving between them, which frees you from having to de-tangle the logic by yourself - fundamentally `yield from` is just three simple ideas:</sub>

  1. <sub>call a method on the iterator to get the next element,</sub>
  2. <sub>how to handle `.send` (which may change the method called in step 1), and</sub>
  3. <sub>how to handle `.throw` (which may change the method called in step 1).</sub>
- <sub>By asking for modest boilerplate at each `yield from` replacement, we can avoid needing any hidden magic with special wrapper types, decorators, and so on.</sub>

<sub>** Python 2.5 is when [PEP-342](https://peps.python.org/pep-0342) made `yield` an expression and added `GeneratorExit`. Though if you are ever unfortunate enough to need to backport or "backpile" (transpile to an older version of the language) this `yield_from` would still do all the hard parts of building `yield from` on top of `yield` for you.</sub>

Also, this idea leaves a lot of freedom for how how usage boilerplate looks. For example,

1. `handle_throw` could be trivially refactored into a context manager, enabling usage like this:

   ```py
   for value, handle_send, handle_throw in yield_from(foo):
       with handle_throw:
           handle_send(yield value)
   ```

   and
2. you could make `value, handle_send, handle_throw` something like a named tuple if you find this usage nicer:

   ```py
   for step in yield_from(foo):
       with step.handle_throw:
           step.handle_send(yield step.value)
   ```