# How to conditionally exclude source files from python setup install

Tags: python, python-3.x, setup.py

My 2.x/3.x python module shows exceptions on install when installing with Python versions before *3.3*.

Some files use `yield from` syntax introduced in Python 3.3, and setup.py tries to compile everything on install, resulting in syntax errors and stack trace displays under versions before *3.3*

The *3.3+* code is isolated in its own files and conditionally imported, so the compile error has no impact on run-time use of the module under any version, but it displays ugly error messages on install, as described above.

I could wrap each *3.3+* code block in a triple-quoted string, eval it, and catch compile errors, but that makes maintenance arbitrarily harder, so I am hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Are you using virtual environments? With virtualenv you can use pip to install the correct version of a library depending on the version of the interpreter.

Comment: That would require producing multiple versions of the library, for pip to choose from. I am trying to avoid that multiple version situation.

Comment: Armin Ronacher wrote a [nice article](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2013/5/21/porting-to-python-3-redux/) about how to support 2.7 and 3.x with the same source code. I wrote [Grako](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/grako/) using those techniques. For other apps, I've found some features of [Six](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six/) useful, but I think it's best to avoid using it.

Comment: As to "yield from", there's an answer at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17581401/545637).