# How do I get the result of a yield from in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.4, coroutine, yield-from

I've got code that looks somewhat like:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def myfunction():
    result = yield from bot.whois(something)  # returns an asyncio.Future()
    return result['account']
```

How would I convert this to something that works in Python 2.7? Is that even possible?

The question [Converting "yield from" statement to Python 2.7 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581332/converting-yield-from-statement-to-python-2-7-code) **isn't** applicable, because it throws away the result.

Comment: Preliminary research shows that this might not be possible without resorting to callbacks or using a Trollius event loop instead of Asyncio https://trollius.readthedocs.org/asyncio.html#differences-between-trollius-and-tulip

Comment: `for result in bot.whois(something): yield result` didn't work? I've also never seen a function with both `yield` and `return`.

Comment: No, it doesn't. `yield from` is quite different. https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

Comment: pep380 specifies an equivalence between yield from and code that returns stuff - however it is quite complex. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/#id13

Comment: `asyncio` isn't compatible with Python 2.x. As you mentioned, you need to use trollius instead.

Comment: `yield from` isn't limited to asyncio though....

Comment: Have you looked at implementing something similar in twisted?

Comment: Switching frameworks would mean tossing out everything I've already got, and that's not really an option for me. I've just tossed Python <3.3 compatibility.