# How to convert version 3.x "yield from" to something compatible in version 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, yield-keyword

This works fine with Python 3.5 .I understand yield from is not available in python 2.7. How can I implement the `depth_first()` function using python 2.7?

The following solution did not help me:
[Converting "yield from" statement to Python 2.7 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581332/converting-yield-from-statement-to-python-2-7-code)

```
class Node:
 def __init__(self, value):
    self._value = value
    self._children = []

 def __repr__(self):
    return 'Node({!r})'.format(self._value)

 def add_child(self, node):
    self._children.append(node)

 def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self._children)

 def depth_first(self):
    yield self
    for c in self:
        yield from c.depth_first()

# Example
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Node(0)
    child1 = Node(1)
    child2 = Node(2)
    root.add_child(child1)
    root.add_child(child2)
    child1.add_child(Node(3))
    child1.add_child(Node(4))
    child2.add_child(Node(5))
    for ch in root.depth_first():
        print(ch)
```

This is the expected output:

```
Node(0), Node(1), Node(3), Node(4), Node(2), Node(5)
```

Comment: @Prune Please look at my question, I specifically gave the link suggesting the solution did not work. Hope you read the question completely

Comment: My apologies.  I reopened this.

Comment: What did you try that didn't work? What error did you get? (It worked for me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `yield from` into a for-loop with plain yield.

Convert `class Node:` into `class Node(object):` to ensure you get a new-style class.

The code now works in Python 2.7.

```
class Node(object):
 def __init__(self, value):
    self._value = value
    self._children = []

 def __repr__(self):
    return 'Node({!r})'.format(self._value)

 def add_child(self, node):
    self._children.append(node)

 def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self._children)

 def depth_first(self):
    yield self
    for c in self:
        for n in c.depth_first():
            yield n

# Example
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Node(0)
    child1 = Node(1)
    child2 = Node(2)
    root.add_child(child1)
    root.add_child(child2)
    child1.add_child(Node(3))
    child1.add_child(Node(4))
    child2.add_child(Node(5))
    for ch in root.depth_first():
        print(ch)
```

Comment: Note: this only works for trivial uses of `yield from`. If the caller is using `g.send` or other generator-specific functions, it does not.