# 'yield from' substitute in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator, yield-from

My code uses [`yield from`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) in `python3` in ***recursive calls*** and it works perfectly fine. The problem right now is that this was *introduced from* [PEP-380](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) in [`python 3.3`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html) and I need it to work in [`python 2.7`](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/). I read up on a few articles and none of them were detailed enough or simple enough.

Few referred articles :

- [Converting “yield from” statement to Python 2.7 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581332/converting-yield-from-statement-to-python-2-7-code)
- [`yield from` and Python 2.7](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/4rc15s/yield_from_and_python_27/)

and few others.

I have recreated a small Sample code *(which takes in a multi-level list and returns a flattened list)* that is ***very minimalistic*** compared to my requirements.

```
#python 3
def foo(obj):
    for ele in obj:
        if isinstance(ele, list):
            yield from foo(ele)
        else:
            yield ele
```

#driver values :

```
>>> l = [1, [2, 3, [4,5]]]
>>> list(foo(l))
=>  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The same converted does not work in `python 2.7` due to the non-availability of `yield from`.

Comment: Why does it have to be recursive? Internally `yield from` is also just a loop.

Comment: Yet `yield from` is, at it's heart, a loop with delegation. You don't need the delegation, but you *still need to loop*.

Comment: Ok. Stupid me. It works. The answers there were bit confusing and I couldn't get it. Let me change the question.

Comment: Note that `yield from` was not introduced in PEP 342. [PEP 380](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) handles `yield from`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : noted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **still need to loop**. It doesn't matter that you have recursion here.

You need to loop over the generator produced by the recursive call and yield the results:

```
def foo(obj):
    for ele in obj:
        if isinstance(ele, list):
            for res in foo(ele):
                yield res
        else:
            yield ele
```

Your recursive call produces a generator, and you need to pass the results of the generator onwards. You do so by looping over the generator and yielding the individual values.

**There are no better options**, other than upgrading to Python 3.

`yield from` essentially passes on the responsibility to loop over to the caller, and passes back any `generator.send()` and `generator.throw()` calls to the delegated generator. You don't have any need to pass on `.send()` or `.throw()`, so what remains is taking responsibility to do the looping yourself.

Demo:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=14, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> def foo(obj):
...     for ele in obj:
...         if isinstance(ele, list):
...             for res in foo(ele):
...                 yield res
...         else:
...             yield ele
...
>>> l = [1, [2, 3, [4,5]]]
>>> list(foo(l))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

`yield from` was introduced in [PEP 380 -- *Syntax for Delegating to a Subgenerator*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) (not PEP 342), specifically because a loop over the sub-generator would not delegate `generator.throw()` and `generator.send()` information.

The PEP explicitly states:

> If yielding of values is the only concern, this can be performed without much difficulty using a loop such as
>
> ```
> for v in g:
>     yield v
> ```

The [*Formal Semantics*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/#formal-semantics) has a Python implementation equivalent that may look intimidating at first, but you can still pick out that it *loops* (with `while 1:`, looping ends when there is an exception or `StopIteration` is handled, new values are retrieved with `next()` or `generator.send(..)`), and yields the results (with `yield _y`).

Comment: Nice answer. As usual. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you say "my code cannot work with loops and needs to be recursive"? You can easily use a loop in a recursive generator:

```
def foo(obj):
    for ele in obj:
        if isinstance(ele, list):
            #yield from foo(ele)
            for t in foo(ele):
                yield t 
        else:
            yield ele

l = [1, [2, 3, [4, 5]]]
print list(foo(l))
```

**output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```